# How to repeat string methods

Tags: string

I have to print:

Ain't no sunshine when she's gone
It's not warm when she's away.
Ain't no sunshine when she's gone
And she's always gone too long
Anytime she goes away.

How would I used methods to print these no loops?

Would it be something like this:

```
public class AintNoSunshine {

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
  String string1 =(" Ain't no sunshine when she's gone! "  );
  System.out.println( string1);

  String string2 = " It's not warm when she's away. ";
  System.out.println( string2);

  String string3 = " And she's always gone too long ";
  System.out.println( string3);

  String string4 = " Anytime she goes away. ";
  System.out.println( string4);


   }
 }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote looks fine, are you getting any errors? It might look a little cleaner if you moved all your print lines to the bottom:

```
public class AintNoSunshine {

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
  String string1 =(" Ain't no sunshine when she's gone! "  );
  String string2 = " It's not warm when she's away. ";
  String string3 = " And she's always gone too long ";
  String string4 = " Anytime she goes away. ";
  System.out.println( string1);
  System.out.println( string2);
  System.out.println( string3);
  System.out.println( string4);
 }
}
```

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors but how would I repeat the lines? Because some lines are repeated several times.